# Generic Software Architecture of Cloud Computing Platforms

Tags: cloud

For past few weeks I was reading different articles, publications, blog postings and so one regarding the generic software architectural model for cloud based applications; and I would be very much interested to know about your own idea about this as well.

Through my reading, I have found the below three types of software architecture in use within current industry focus for different types of web-based distributed applications.

1. MVC - there are nowadays a large number of frameworks available based on it like Spring, Struts2, JBoos Seam, JSF, ASP.net MVC, Ruby-on-Rails, CakePHP, Zend, Django and so on. Microsoft's cloud computing platform Azure is also providing good integration and migration paths for MVC based applications in the cloud.
2. 3-Tier - architectural model represents a good separation of different tiers and distributed layers thus from the emergence of web based applications it played a key role for the software architect to design a robust platform for their need. However, it seems with the advent of MVC frameworks and their ease of use make 3-tier architecture a second choice for many. Surprisingly, Google's cloud platform AppEngine has offered their migration strategies in such a way which mostly give a message of clean separation of "stateless computing tier" and "stateful storage tier" thus supporting the prime base of 3-tier based architecture. And I found statements like MS Azure supports general-purpose computing rather than a specific type of application like what is supported by GAE.
3. SOA and REST - based applications are now emerging in a great speed primarily due to mobile computing platforms, service-oriented offerings and good similarities with the standard Internet protocols for communication in distributed computing like HTTP, XML, UDDI, WSDL and SOAP. Emerging applications like Facebook, Twitter and other social networking hypes are mostly using RESTful architectural model for their mobile platforms and future trends are also showing a stable focus with the enhance usages of JAX-WS/RS, Jersey, Restlet, RestEeasy, Microsoft's WCF, Apache CXF and Axis2. Now, if we look in accordance with cloud computing principle, many of the Internet writers are showing how it evolves from SOA and SaaS but it is not clearly mention that how these two concepts are integrated and inter-operable with each other. Again, how SOA and SaaS based applications can able to migrate to cloud platforms it is still not fully clear and visible. The phrase "Mobile Cloud Computing" is now seems in many Internet pages but how it actually works in accordance with SaaS and Utility based computing it may still unknown from a view of a software architect.

To this end, we have now three different kind of architectural models which all have some similarities, many variances and so other critical brain reasoning facts but these can be inter-operable and how they can be migrated to the Internet Giant's (like Azure, GAE or AWS) cloud offerings are still not fully apparent and indicates more brain storming for the passionate in this capital research globe to integrate business and technology together.

It would be great to hear your voice with more examples, comments and explanations as well as criticism :) in this regard as I am just a newbie in this arena and still learning.

Thanks a lot ....

Comment: You'd be better off posting this as a blog entry. It's much too open-ended for this forum.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 5):

Your categorization is not fair. There are lots of architectures in the cloud applications that needs more investigation. You may take a look at [this resource](http://webpages.iust.ac.ir/hsalimi/Courses/89-90-1/CC/Semibars/Cloud%20application%20architecture.pptx) and its references for more info. For more topics on the cloud, take a look at [this page](http://webpages.iust.ac.ir/hsalimi/Courses/89-90-1/CC/CloudComputing.html) too. It may help.

Comment: Hi Salimi, 

Thanks a lot for your comment and the links. Its really great to see other types of classification like as mentioned in the article "Choosing an application architecture for the cloud": 
Traditional architecture;
asynchronous application architecture; and
Synchronous application architecture.


Thanks.